# Installing google api client to send emails from python

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm trying to learn how to send emails in python using the Gmail API.

One of the first lines in my script:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

gives me the error:

```
No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

I am trying to install googleapiclient by doing:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

which seems to do all the right things until the end when it says:

```
Installing collected packages: httplib2, uritemplate, rsa, cachetools, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, google-auth-httplib2, google-api-python-client
  Found existing installation: httplib2 0.9.1
Cannot uninstall 'httplib2'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I wasn't sure if this message would stop thing from working, but I am still getting the message:

```
No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

when I try to run my code. Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Try `pip uninstall httplib2` and run this `sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client` again or check if the package is installed already `pip show  google-api-python-client`.

Comment: I get the same message when I try to uninstall: Cannot uninstall 'httplib2'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: I suggest you to try installing the packages using `pip install --user google-api-python-client` after uninstalling it using `pip uninstall google-api-python-client`.

Comment: That got it thank you!

Comment: If that didn't solve your problem, please do check this [page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247). It is dealing with similar issue.

Comment: Great to know that i did solve your problems. I will post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is facing a similar issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247).

Using the `--user` option to install the package will solve this issue in most cases. Before installing the package. We must uninstall `google-api-python-client` first.

```
pip uninstall google-api-python-client
```

Now `install` the package using the `--user` option.

```
pip install --user google-api-python-client
```